# Convertion C to Golang with windows.h

Tags: c, go, dll, type-conversion

I want to convert this code in C, that works pretty well

```
#include <windows.h>

void main() {
    double* mdl_G;
    void* dll = LoadLibrary("./test_win64.dll");
    mdl_G     = ((double*)GetProcAddress(dll, "G"));
    printf("G = %.2f",*mdl_G);
}
```

to GoLang. I just tried this tip, but doesn`t work:

```
func main() {

    dll, _ := syscall.LoadDLL("./test_win64.dll")
    mdl_G, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(dll.Handle, "G")
    real_G := (*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&mdl_G))
    log.Print(*real_G)

}
```

But doesnt work.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows, but I would assume `mdl_G` is the pointer you need, not the value you want to cast as a `float64`

Comment: I will update the example code. But that's basically it Jim.

Comment: You're still taking the address of `mdl_G`, which is saying you want to cast that value as a `float64`, not what it points to.

Comment: The error is (*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&mdl_G), that must be (*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(mdl_G). It's works, but VSCode report that is a misuse of unsafe.Pointer

Comment: It probably says "_possible_ misuse of unsafe.Pointer" as a warning, because you should never store a Go pointer as a `uintptr`. `mdl_G` is not allocated by Go, so it's OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is & operator in unsafe pointer.
The method GetProcAddress already return a uintptr.

```
func main() {

    dll, _ := syscall.LoadDLL("./test_win64.dll")
    mdl_G, _ := syscall.GetProcAddress(dll.Handle, "G")
    real_G := (*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(mdl_G)) // this conversion is safe.
    log.Print(*real_G)

}
```

Go vet will reports a possible misuse of function. But, that is correct according: [allow conversion of uintptr to unsafe.Pointer when it points to non-Go memory #58625](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/58625)